# Trigger Email Alert on KillW3wp Event

Tags: iis, iis-8

There's an option to have an IIS Application Pool automatically kill w3wp if the process runs at over some threshold for some period.  Ref: [Kill w3wp.exe if it is working on 100% cpu over a period of time](https://serverfault.com/questions/250701/kill-w3wp-exe-if-it-is-working-on-100-cpu-over-a-period-of-time)

When such an event occurs, I'd like to trigger a mail such that we're aware that there had been an issue; thus we'll know:

- any users reporting issues before the alert will likely have had their issue resolved by the KillW3wp event.
- any users reporting issues at the point of KillW3wp would suggest unwanted side effects caused by the kill.
- we can search for patterns in when this fix is needed / in data in the related logs from the same time, from which we can delve deeper into finding the underlying cause.

**Question:**

- Is it possible to trigger an email when KillW3wp is initiated?
- Alternatively, does anyone know the EventId, Source & Log we'd need to monitor to detect this issue (we could thus use the windows scheduler to trigger the mail; http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2010/06/16/getting-event-log-contents-by-email-on-an-event-log-trigger.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `KillW3wp` doesn't support additional actions that I am aware of.

Fret not, there is an event log for the action.

- Product: Internet Information Services
- ID: 5025
- Source: Microsoft-Windows-WAS
- Version: 7.0
- Symbolic Name: WAS_EVENT_JOB_LIMIT_HIT
- Message: Application pool '%1' exceeded its job limit settings.

Source: [Technet Event ID 5025 — IIS Application Pool Availability](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735237%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)